# How to setup an InfoPath 2010 control to have select all items capability for multiple select List box items

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath 2010 browser based form (from forms library) with several controls and there is a section of the form with several multiple selection list box controls (questions) that is tied to external Data- a filtered (unique filter for each question) list of items pulled from a single SharePoint list with metadata.

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to setup (no code solution) a 'Select all' functionality so that when you click on something, all the items under that question(Multi select list box control) get automatically selected.
2. When I open the form in browser, selecting each check box under a question creates a weird lag and a scroll bar appears abruptly and goes away each time a selection is made (even through there is enough vertical and horizontal space for the question to expand). This is creating a somewhat bad user experience and performance issue. Any recommendation to address this issue?

Thank you for your time and any help or guidance is much appreciated.